# Refresh control target action not triggered

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, tableview, uitabbarcontroller, uirefreshcontrol

My viewcontroller has a tableview, in which i populate my views in different sections. I am trying to add a refresh control to this tableview. What I have implemented is as below.

```
func setUpRefreshControl() {
    let refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
    refreshControl.tintColor = UIColor.red
    refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleRefresh(_: )), for: UIControlEvents.valueChanged)
    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        tableView.refreshControl = refreshControl
    } else {
        tableView.addSubview(refreshControl)
    }
}


@objc func handleRefresh(_ sender: UIRefreshControl) {
   print("-----------REFRESHED------------")
}
```

Next, when I pull down the tableview to refresh, the refresh control (red in color as setup)is visible. However, the target function is not called.

My viewcontroller is inside a tab bar controller, which is embedded in a navigation controller. I guess the issue is related to view hierarchy because when I try the same code in a separate project with no nav bar and tab bar, its working fine. But I cannot figure out what the current issue is. Any suggestion on solving this? Thank you.

**EDIT:** I tested it in different simulators: 6, 6s, 6s+, 7, 7+, 8, 8+, X. I found that the above code runs fine in all the plus versions including X. However, all the simulators are running ios 11.2 so I still cannot figure it out what might be causing this issue.

Comment: I don't think there is issue with view hierarchy here if you able to see the red refresh control. you can try to have that refresh control property  global to check that

Comment: You can uncheck under top bar and adjust automatic scrollview inset from storyboard also to try

Comment: didn't work @PrashantTukadiya, I tried making the refresh control global and also tried changing the scroll content insets

Answer (score 10):

I was having a similar issue, pull to refresh would work fine on 5.5" screens but all other phones would show only a partial animation then never quite trigger the refresh.

I found invoking `refreshControl.didMoveToSuperview()` in the `viewDidAppear` for my view controller fixed the problem.

If I understand correctly, this same method is invoked when you set `tableView.refreshControl = refreshControl` but needs recalculation by the time the view is actually set to appear. I'll need to dig in a bit more to be sure of the specifics, but hope this is helpful for the time being.

Comment: This did it for me

Answer (score 8):

I solved this issue changing the property Size in Simulated Metrics to Inferred and the property Simulated Size to Fixed in the view controller.

I hope this works for you.

Comment: To both use custom simulated size and let refresh control call the refresh method add the solution proposed by thetoneworlf : call refreshControl.didMoveToSuperview() in viewdidappear

Answer (score 1):

This is the refresh control code which i implemented and its working for me in my current project, just 3 days ago.

`var refreshControl: UIRefreshControl!`

this is my global `refreshControl` variable and below is the implementation of it.

```
    //MARK: - REFRESH CONTROLLER VIEW
    refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
    refreshControl.attributedTitle = NSAttributedString(string: "Pull to refresh")
    refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(refresh(_ :)), for: UIControlEvents.valueChanged)
    refreshControl.attributedTitle = NSAttributedString(string: "")
    tblRequest.addSubview(refreshControl)
```

Hope, this works for you ! :-)